# Getting min and mix value for a dictionary that contains both words and numbers

Tags: python, dictionary, max, average, min

So I'm very new to python and have a project for class where we are only allowed to use basic functions. I have created a dictionary based off user input, however, not I am tasked with finding the max and min values.

If my dictionary contains (example):

```
[{'Apples': 13, 'Chips': 12, 'Nuts': 2}]
```

How would I find the min and max values? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please read the posting guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider revising your question to include what you have already attempted.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: your question is not clear, you said you want the min and max values, but you selected a wrong answer. you selected the key corresponding to max and min values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mydict = {'Apples': 13, 'Chips': 12, 'Nuts': 2}

max(mydict.values())

min(mydict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve key with max / min value, following code would work:

```
d = {'Apples': 13, 'Chips': 12, 'Nuts': 2}

max(d, key=d.get)
```

Output:

```
Apples
```

If you need to iterate over dictionary, code could look like following:

```
max = list(d.values())[0]
max_key = list(d.keys())[0]
for k, v in d.items():
  max = max if max > v else v
  max_key = max_key if max > v else k
print(max_key,  max)
```

Comment: Do you know of a way without using key or .values?

Comment: I updated answer with the iteration over dictionary